# Weighted mean using aggregate across groups in r

Tags: r, aggregate, data-management

I want to take the weighted mean of a group using the aggregate function in r.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
set.seed(1980)
Group_1 <- sample(letters[1:4], 50, TRUE)
Group_2 <- sample(letters[8:13], 50, TRUE)
Weight <- sample(seq(1,50), 50, TRUE)
Value <- sample(seq(1,50), 50, TRUE)

DF <- data.frame(Group_1, Group_2, Weight, Value)

head(DF)
```

I want to take the weighted mean of the `Value` column, using the `Weight` column, for each pairwise group.

Such that, the aggregate function would look like:

```
aggregate(Value ~ Group_1 + Group_2, data = df, mean)
```

How would I take the weighted mean using the aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `mean`, use `weighted.mean`.  However, `aggregate`, may not be an option here because `aggregate` loop over only the 'Value' column and it doesn't have access to the 'Weight' for each group

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
     group_by(Group_1, Group_2) %>%
     summarise(wt_mean = weighted.mean(Value, Weight), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 21 x 3
# Groups:   Group_1 [4]
#   Group_1 Group_2 wt_mean
#   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 a       h         24.7 
# 2 a       i         15   
# 3 a       j         21.1 
# 4 a       k         23.6 
# 5 a       m         14.1 
# 6 b       i         40   
# 7 b       j         12.7 
# 8 b       k          6.88
# 9 b       l         30.6 
10 b       m          5   
# … with 11 more rows
```

---

If we want to use `base R`, then `by` should work

```
by(DF, DF[c('Group_1', 'Group_2')], function(x) weighted.mean(x$Value, x$Weight))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help! I really appreciate it!